# Knowing that $\phi$ is a characteristic function, show that $e^{\phi-1}$ is also a characteristic function

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions

Knowing that $\phi$ is a characteristic function of a random variable $X$, how to show that $e^{\phi-1}$ is also a characteristic function of some random variable.

I tried this way:
$e^{\phi-1}=e^{-1}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{\phi^k}{k!}=e^{-1}E(\phi^Y)$ where $Y$ has $Pois(1)$ distribution.

Suppose that $X_i$ iid with the same distribution as $X$,
$e^{-1}E(\phi^Y)=e^{-1}E(E(e^{\sum_{i=1}^YitX_i}))=e^{-1}E(E(E(e^{\sum_{i=1}^YitX_i}|Y)))$.

And I got stuck here, because I don't see it to prove anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E{e^{{it\sum_1 ^{Y} X_j}}=\sum_n e^{-1} \frac 1 {n!} {\phi (t)}^{n}}=e^{\phi (t) -1}$. In the first step I assumed that Y is independent of the $X_j$'s so that I can condition on $\{Y=n\}$ and then sum over n. The last step is just summing the exponential series.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\sum_ne^{-1}\frac{1}{n!}\phi(t)^n=E\phi^Y=E(Ee^{it\sum_{j}^Y X_j})$?

Comment: I don't understand the first equality, could you give some intermediate steps?
I mean, when you condition $Ee^{it\sum_{j}^Y X_j}$ on Y, this is not already expected value of $Y$ but of $X$, right?
If so, why here $\sum_ne^{-1}\frac{1}{n!}\phi^n$ are you using the distribution of $Y$?

Comment: $Ee^{it \sum_1 ^{n} X_j }=\phi (t) ^{n}$ for any positive integer n. So when you condition on $Y$ you get the same expression with $n$ changed to $Y$. Now multiply by $P\{Y=n\}$ and sum over n. This is how you get that first equation in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand.
The first equation in your answer is $\phi^Y=\sum_n P(Y=n)\phi^n$, right?
Is this equality true?

Comment: You missed expectation on the left side. $E\phi ^{Y} =\sum P\{Y=n\}\phi ^{n}$. Expectation is an integral and you have to split the integral into integral over the disjoint events $\{Y=n\}$, n=1,2,.. to get this formula.

Comment: But $Ee^{it\sum_1^YX_j}$ isn't $\phi^Y$? This is first equality in your solution

Comment: Y is a random variable so you will not get $\phi ^{Y}$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you have just solved the problem.

Just suppose $\xi=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_Y$ where $Y$ follows a Poisson distribution with event rate $1$ and $\{X_i\}_{i \ge 1}$ is a family of identically independent random variables whose characteristic functions are both $\phi(t)$. Then we have $\mathbb{E} e^{it\xi} = e^{\phi-1}$.